# Is it illegal to copy specific website page text onto a word document?

Tags: copyright

Let's say I found some useful information on a webpage I wanted to save for future reference. Is it legal to save that text onto a word document for my own personal reference? I have no intention of distributing said document for commercial use or profit.

Comment: What scope? What kind of text? Is it under license (e.g. Wikipedia, SE)? Do you have intention to distribute it *at all*?

Comment: As far as scope, it could be a sentence or a paragraph. Let's assume it is under license. There is no intention to distribute at all.

Comment: @James Under **what** license? I think what you mean to ask is what's the case if no license conditions at all are stated, which is the most common and the worst case.

Comment: As far as license, let's say I do a Google search and just want to copy the sentence answer in bold?

Comment: Google Search does **not** grant you any license, it explicitly says "Check the linked page what or if a license applies"

Comment: However, the specific context of copying text is purely for personal use. Wouldn't this simple context I'm describing fall under fair use?

Comment: See also: [How is internet archiving legal, when it appears to violate many websites terms of use?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27407/how-is-internet-archiving-legal-when-it-appears-to-violate-many-websites-terms)

Comment: @James The problem with fair use is that only a court can really say, and it depends on four factors, including the nature of the copyrighted work that you're copying (e.g. non-fiction or fiction). But no copyright holder can practically take you to court over this until you redistribute it.

Comment: You are just rehashing the same theme here James, the answer should be the same whether it's a PDF, Word, Powerpoint, Publisher, ad naseum...

Comment: It seems nonsensical that it is illegal to copy a small string of text for purely noncommercial use. How is it not legal when businesses engage in mass webscraping for profit purposes? Obviously everyone does this whether they're aware of it or not and there is no way any legal action would be possible to enforce the exact scenario I am describing. If this is illegal, it is completely divorced from common sense.

Comment: “It seems nonsensical that it is illegal to copy a small string of text for purely noncommercial use.”…. ”it is completely divorced from common sense.”  Agree, maybe that explains the downvotes?!

Comment: @James You can say the same about almost any activity that you find harmless and wish were legal. "It seems nonsensical that it is illegal to smoke a small amount of cannabis in the privacy of my own home, ..." etc. Insert your favourite illegal activity there.

Comment: No, it's different because with regards to intellectual property, in specific context, we're dealing with intangible ideas and the act of writs and prose. Millions of people are committing copyright and they don't even realize it which is absurd. It's far different than the cannabis example which is a poor one at that.