# reproducing data from one website on another

Tags: copyright, internet

I'm making a website that translates original content scraped from other websites and reproduces it on my own website.  The content on the source websites is not behind a paywall, nor does one need to be a member to access it.  Also, the the original website is referenced as a source wherever data is used.

I found [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/is-it-legal-to-download-a-website-and-display-it-on-another-that-i-own), which may be related, but I will only be reproducing text.

Does the [Supreme Court ruling against LinkedIn](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2019/09/victory-ruling-hiq-v-linkedin-protects-scraping-public-data) apply here?

Comment: The main issue with your plan is that regardless of what the Supreme Court ruling says about the scraping, you have a problem with copyright because your intention is to create a directly derivative work form the scraped data and distribute it - that’s not what the MS v hiQ case involved.  Do you have permission to redistribute, ie is the original content under an open license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is *prima facie* Copyright breach

You don’t own the copyright in the other website. Copyright law says you can’t make translations without permission of the copyright owner.

Unless you meet fair use/dealing criteria (which we cannot assess from you info but it seems unlikely).

Comment: Fair use unlikely? Tell it Google Translate (which translates any website just with a click).

Comment: @Greendrake Google Translate tends to translate in context, it makes it *very* obvious it’s the original website translated on demand and not a reproduction.  The OPs description of what they intend does not match what Google Translate does.